# SQL If-Else logic based on value of one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following tables:

**Production Table**

```
SerialNumber  WorkOrderNumber  ItemName   ItemType
   1234           A2234          ASD        1
   1234           A2234          ASD-T      2 
   1111           B2234          ZXC-T      2
```

**WorkOrder Table**

```
WorkOrderNumber ItemName ItemType 
     B2234         ZXC       1
     B2234         ZXC-T     2
     B2234         ZXC-C     3
```

Scenario: User inputs Serial Number, wants to get the item name of itemtype = 1 from either production table or workorder table

**Desired Result**

User input Serial number 1234 in application:

ItemName : ASD [Found in production table]

User input Serial number 1111 in application:

ItemName : ZXC [Found in workorder table]

Production and Workorder table is heavily simplified for demonstration purposes. The table contains millions of rows each. I need to come up with a performant query to get the item name.

The only solution I have thought of is to do the following

1. Use stored procedure and write an if-else logic

   - Check if the item type of the entered serial number is 1. If true, return itemname.
   - If itemtype is not 1, get the itemname from workorder table with itemtype = 1

But I'm not sure if that's a preferred method for performance and I feel kinda icky about putting business logic in database.

How would one handle this problem elegantly?

Comment: I don't understand how serial 1111 could ever return ASD - they're on separate rows.

Comment: Shouldn't SerialNumber be a PK on Production table?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Ugh, stupid me. I've accidently switched the serial number in the example. Fixed.

Comment: You could do it in your SQL, or you could do it in your application. You can analyze the results when they return from the SP, and if your dataset/whatever has data, then you can display it. Otherwise you can display a message or do whatever erorr handling you wish. This is what a try/catch block is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select top 1 pt.serialNumber,pt.workOrderNumber,
       isNull(wt.ItemName,pt.ItemName) as NameToReturn
from prodTable pt
left join worktable wt on pt.WorkOrderNumber=wt.workOrderNumber and wt.itemType=1
where pt.serialNumber = <input>
order by p1.itemType
```

Not sure I understand all your requirements, but the above should give you a start point.  It finds the part in the prodTable and optionally finds a part in the work Item table.   The is Null logic assumes that if  a type one exists in Work table, it will be used.   You might need to tweak this to a case statement if your rules are different (i.e. 1 in prod table should override worktable)

Comment: Nah, that's brilliant, definitely out of the box thinking for me. This should be all I need to get started. Thank you.